# Trouble upgrading to EF 6 with Breeze.js

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze

I have just updated a new project with Nuget to try and use the latest packages for MVC 5.1, EF 6.1, and the latest Breeze.js v1.4.11 (the package for EF 6).  When I try to retrieve the metadata from my BreezeController I recieve the following error.

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.
```

I have gone through some of the older questions regarding this type of problem, but it seems as though most of those problems would have been addressed by using the new Breeeze.js specifically built for EF 6+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I was referencing the EFContextProvider<> in Breeze.WebApi.EF instead of the one in Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.  I think I understand why they did this, backwards compatibility.  Changing my reference solved the issue.